# Ruby + AMQP: processing queue in parallel

Tags: ruby, amqp

Since most of my tasks depends on the network, I want to process my queue in parallel, not just one message at a time.

So, I'm using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require "rubygems"
require 'amqp'

EventMachine.run do
  connection = AMQP.connect(:host => '127.0.0.1')

  channel  = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
  channel.prefetch 5

  queue    = channel.queue("pending_checks", :durable => true)
  exchange = channel.direct('', :durable => true)

  queue.subscribe(:ack => true) do |metadata, payload|
    time = rand(3..9)
    puts 'waiting ' + time.to_s + ' for message ' + payload
    sleep(time)

    puts 'done with '+ payoad

    metadata.ack
  end
end
```

Why it is not using my prefetch setting? I guess it should get 5 messages and process them in parallel, no?

Comment: Fernando, it seems to me that joelparkerhenderson's answer, below, is useful. Did it help solve your problem? Let us know either way.

Answer (score 2):

Prefetch is the maximum number of messages that may be sent to you in advance before you ack.

In other words, the prefetch size does not limit the transfer of single messages to a client, only the sending in advance of more messages while the client still has one or more unacknowledged messages.  (From AMPQ docs)

[QoS Prefetching Messages](http://rubydoc.info/github/ruby-amqp/amqp/master/file/docs/Queues.textile#QoS___Prefetching_messages)

[RabbitMQ AMQP Reference](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html)

EventMachine is single threaded and event based. For parallel jobs on different threads or processes, see EM::Deferrable, then Thread or spawn.

Also see Hot Bunnies, a fast DSL on top of the RabbitMQ Java client:

https://github.com/ruby-amqp/hot_bunnies

(Thanks for info from Michael Klishin on Google Groups, and stoyan on blogger)

Comment: And do you know how to make Ruby amqp process the queue tasks in parallel?

Comment: Updated the answer with how to make processing parallel